# Solving linear equations using division of matrix determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I did not know that we can use this method to solve linear equations and was wondering what method is called. Thank you so much

Comment: Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), rather than using images, and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is called [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#:%7E:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20Cramer%27s%20rule,system%20has%20a%20unique%20solution.&text=Cramer%27s%20rule%20implemented%20in%20a,than%20two%20or%20three%20equations.). Namely, let $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ be a system of linear equations such that $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $\det(A)\neq 0$. Then we have a unique solution $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$ with
$$x_i=\frac{\det(A_i)}{\det(A)},$$
where $A_i$ is the square matrix obtained by replacing the $i$-th column of $A$ by the column vector $\mathbf{b}$.